# Write a filter in idiomatic javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this filter, which I don't like:

```
var products = this.store.filter('product', function(product) {
    var ok = true;
    if (compatibility) {
        ok = ok && product.compatibility == compatibility;
    }
    if (format) {
        ok = ok && product.format == format;
    }
    if (priceRange) {
        ok = ok && product.priceRange == priceRange;
    }
    if (productType) {
        ok = ok && product.productType == productType;
    }
    return ok;
});
```

Basically, the filter function must return `true` for products which pass the test, and `false` for those which don't pass the test. The filter parameters can have a value of be `null` .

What is the more idiomatic way of rewriting the filter function?

Comment: Well, you could use a helper function that compares multiple properties at once which would be more declarative, or convert it to a simple `return false` on negative cases which'd make the function just 5 lines long. However, I'd pass the code review as is.

Comment: `if (compatibility && product.compatibility != compatibility) return;`

Comment: What is `'product'` doing in `filter('product', …)`?

Comment: @gfullam: that's an Ember method to filter elements from the store. Not really related to the question: I am just interested in the filter itself (the `function(product) ...` part)

Answer (score 2):

For every test that fails, `return false;` immediately. There is no point in processing further if you know it's failed.

```
if( compatibility && product.compatibility != compatibility) {
    return false;
}
// ...
return true;
```

Alternatively, (**hint: don't do this!**), you could do a really long one-liner:

```
return (!compatibility || product.compatibility == compatibility) && (!format || product.format == format) // ...
// interestingly this shortcuts just like the "immediately return false" solution
```

Comment: you should maybe put parens around the `&&` expression, even though it doesn't matter